# Colouring text based on color codes in a JTextPane dynamicly

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextpane

I'm trying to make a textpane using a StyledDocument where when doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text + "\n", keyWord); it replaces all instances of "§" then a number (so like "§1") with the colour and should remove the code its self after and leave the text coloured. The code is able to colour and remove but the issue is that the when I remove the text from the actual doc(the textpane) the local variable I have isn't updated, and I am not sure what the best way to do that would be(the local variable is "text"). The issue with this is that it starts deleting things that aren't the code, I assume that is caused by the wrong index.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Label;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import me.woder.bot.Client;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class TorchGUI extends JPanel{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public JFrame frame;
  private JTextField textField;
  Client c;
  JTextPane chat;
  JTextArea status;

  final StyleContext cont = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  final AttributeSet black = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(),     StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(0,0,0));
  final AttributeSet blue = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(0,0,170));
  final AttributeSet green = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(0,170,0));
  final AttributeSet dark_aqua = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(0,170,170));
  final AttributeSet dark_red = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(170,0,0));
  final AttributeSet purple = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(170,0,170));
  final AttributeSet orange = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(255,170,0));
  final AttributeSet grey = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(170,170,170));
  final AttributeSet dark_grey = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(85,85,85));
  final AttributeSet indigo = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(85,85,255));
  final AttributeSet bright_green = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(85,255,85));
  final AttributeSet aqua = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(85,255,255));
  final AttributeSet red = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(255,85,85));
  final AttributeSet pink = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(255,85,255));
  final AttributeSet yellow = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(255,255,85));
  final AttributeSet white = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(255,255,255));
  final AttributeSet reset = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.black);
  final AttributeSet attrBlack = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLACK);
  DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  };

/** launch it up
 * 
 */public static void main(String[] args){
     TorchGUI window;
     window = new TorchGUI();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
     window.addText("§0this should be black §1this should be blue");
  }


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public TorchGUI(/*Client c*/) {
    //this.c = c;
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("TorchBot 2.1");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 944, 555);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 520, 454);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    chat = new JTextPane(doc);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(chat);
    chat.setEditable(false);


    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(10, 476, 447, 33);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    status = new JTextArea();
    status.setBounds(540, 250, 262, 215);
    frame.getContentPane().add(status);
    status.setEditable(false);

    JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_2.setBounds(540, 12, 262, 228);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_2);

}

public void addText(String text){
    SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    try {
        int len = doc.getLength();
        doc.insertString(len, text + "\n", keyWord);
        formatColour(text, len);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void formatColour(String text, int offset){
    System.out.println("Text: " + text + " length + " + text.length() + " offset is: " + offset);
    int before = offset;
    if (before < 0) before = 0;
    int after = text.length();
    int wordL = before;
    int wordR = before;

    while (wordR < after) {
        /*boolean is = true;
        if (wordR == after || is) {*/
       try{
            System.out.println("Now looking at:" + text.substring(wordL, wordR) + " wordR is: " + wordR + " and offset is: " + offset + " worldL is: " + wordL);
          if(text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("§") && text.length() >= (wordR+1-offset)){
            if (text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("0")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), black, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("1")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), blue, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("2")){                        
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), green, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("3")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), dark_aqua, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("4")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), dark_red, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("5")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), purple, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("6")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), orange, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("7")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), grey, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("8")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), dark_grey, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("9")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), indigo, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("a")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), bright_green, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("b")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), aqua, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("c")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), red, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("d")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), pink, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("e")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), yellow, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("f")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), white, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else if(text.substring(wordL, wordR+1).contains("r")){
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, text.length(), reset, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 2);
            }else{
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlack, false);
                doc.remove(wordL, 1);
            }            
        }
      wordL = wordR;  
      wordR++;
     } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to use a loop to get rid of all that repetition. Otherwise you'll have a mess to debug.

Comment: You should make your modifications before calling super.insertString, IMHO

Comment: Perhaps a DocumentFilter would be more suited to the job...

Comment: I have tried doing that and it changed nothing

Comment: `"I have tried doing that and it change nothing"` -- tells us nothing. If you've tried something, show the code, and the errors if any. Preferably post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WsjXi8fE is the entire class, you can compile it and it should run but its a really big mess since I have been trying to get this thing to work using various methods.

Comment: The SSCCE should be posted here, not on pastbin. `it should run but its a really big mess` - we are not interested in reading messy code. We are here to do you a favour and help you with your problem. The least you can do is post a proper SSCCE the WILL run and is readable.

Comment: @camickr I have updated the question with what you have asked, I am sorry I did not realize that you don't like external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse the text BEFORE you add it to the Document.

You would also want to get rid of the if/else statements. Anytime you see a structure like that you know you have a design problem.

Here is the approach I would use:

```
public void addText(String text)
{
    HashMap<String, AttributeSet> attributes = new HashMap<String, AttributeSet>();
    attributes.put("0", black);
    attributes.put("1", blue);

    String[] lines = text.split("%");

    for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        String line = lines[i];
        String key = line.substring(0, 1);
        String theText = line.substring(1);
        AttributeSet attribute = attributes.get(key);

        try
        {
            int len = doc.getLength();
            doc.insertString(len, theText, attribute);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of defining all the colours as constants I would just put the attribute into the map and this would be done as part of initializing the GUI, since you don't want to rebuild the Map every time you invoke the addText() method.

Also, I change my code to search for an "%", since I don't know what that other character is, so you will need to change that back to your special delimiter. Actually, you should define a constant variable to contain the delimiter value.

Finally, you should NOT be using setBounds() with your GUI components. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: does that code actually work or does it require modification(I understand the concept of what you are telling me to do, but the how still gets me).

Comment: Yes it works. I didn't do any error checking or add your newline string.